# DatastoreTimeoutException in app engine for basic query

Tags: google-app-engine, timeout, google-cloud-datastore

We have started to get a lot of DatastoreTimeoutException lately for this basic query:

```
select id from Later where at < '2013-07-04' limit 500 (Some Pseudo SQL)
```

In code it looks like:

```
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    Query query = new Query("Later").setKeysOnly();
    Filter f = new FilterPredicate("at",FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, new Date());
    query.setFilter(f);
    query.addSort("at", SortDirection.DESCENDING);

    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);
    return pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(500));
```

The table have aprox. 1.5 million entities. Is this normal datastore behavior?

UPDATE: If we remove the filter it is working better. Of course we need the filter so thats not an solution in the long run.

Comment: A week or 2 ago there were issues with datastore timeouts. Are you still getting this issue lately?

Comment: Yes, we are geting it right now.

Comment: Is this happening in a normal web request? i.e. is it the 30 second response limit that's kicking in? If this is a client facing request, maybe do smaller fetch sizes? (not a solution, but another option). See if you get the same timeout if you run the query in a task (which has 10 minute limit).

Comment: No this is happening in a task, and the timeout exeception is thrown after 60 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Change to using `asIterator` instead of `asList`.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Retrieving_results):

> When iterating through the results of a query using the
>   PreparedQuery.asIterable() and PreparedQuery.asIterator() methods, the
>   Datastore retrieves the results in batches. By default each batch
>   contains 20 results, but you can change this value using
>   FetchOptions.chunkSize(). You can continue iterating through query
>   results until all are returned or the request times out.